# Making Cross browser mobile compatibility

Tags: javascript, html, css, cross-browser

***functionality:***

A web App that is viewable in all mobile web browser. Therefore, the web app created needs to be mobile and cross browser compatible and responsive.

***what has been done:***

I edited the CSS as well as include in `<meta name="viewport" author ="Luke" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">`

***ISSUE***

When tested, the following web app fits the Google Chrome Web Browser screen perfectly, the only minor issue is that, the original display is zoomed, hence user has to zoom out

However, when tested on other browser: iOS safari, firefox and android's native web application, IE, the issue is apparent.

The behaviour of the issue is that the display does not fit those browser screens mentioned, in fact it has a lot of white spaces at the bottom and the right of the screen.

Therefore, how am I able to set the `viewport` to be cross browser compatible or is there another way?

```css
 #my-memory-game {
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 }
 body,
 html {
   height: 1920px;
   width: 1080px;
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
 }
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" author="ErnestLee" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is you're setting static dimensions to your screen with the height and width attribute:

```
html {
    height: 1920px;
    width: 1080px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
 }
```

You need to set something like "width=100%" for any kind of flexibility. you're basically creating a fixed width site, so not responsive at all.

If you're looking for a quick and easy way to get stuff working in all browsers I'd get in to a CSS framework. There's heaps to choose from

You can go from simple and barebones like Kube to Foundation. They've just got a lot of inbuilt functions to help you get going and make sure it works on all browsers.

I used to be an advocate of "build your own" but a 1 man band creating a CSS framework compared to the team that work on things like foundation, you're not going to get close.

Comment: I have set the `html, body{}` to 100%. What is worse now is that the background image set within my first <div> tag is only showing about a quarter of the entire image. It is strange since I have set the width and height of the image to be 100%  as well. Lastly, I have tried it with IE and it is still having the same issue.

Comment: If you're looking to get a full background image here's a good place to start http://sixrevisions.com/css/responsive-background-image/